# How to list lsf resources

Tags: linux, lsf

During normal work, I always saw the bsub command like:

`bsub -q int_l -R "ruseage [specman=1:nc_specman=1:evc_verisity_ahb=1:evc_verisity_axi=1:e    vc_v_ahb=1:vxl=1:duration=5]&&select[osname=='redhat'&&oslevel=='5'&&specman>1&&nc_specman>1&&evc_verisity_axi>1&&vxl>1]"`

How can I find the resources defined here, for example, I saw the resource name osname, but how to find other resources by LSF command?

Thanks.

Comment: `man lsf` ? Sorry, but this Q is not about programming as defined for StackOverflow. It **may** be more appropriate on the S.E. related sites http://unix.stackexchange.com (Unix & Linux) OR http://superuser.com . Consider using the `flag` link at the bottom of your Q and ask the moderator to move it. Please don't post the same Q on 2 different sites. Thanks and Good Luck.

Comment: You can read all about resources [in the manual](http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSWRJV_10.1.0/lsf_resource_sharing/chap_rep_lsf_resources.html)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because RTFM

Answer (score 3):

One command may be help, it is lsinfo.